# Set cookies and return user on Cypress request

Tags: cypress

### Problem

I have a Cypress command where I can login with a random user. The API will return the following response:

```json
{
  user: { ... }
  token: { ... }
}
```

What I would like to do is to:

1. Create user using `cy.request`
2. Set the cookie in the browser
3. Return the response out of the command so that I can work with it outside of the command

### What I have tried

```js
return cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: getApiUrl('__cypress__/login'),
    body: requestBody,
    log: false,
  })
    .then(({ body }) => {
      cy
        .setCookie('_token', body.token.plainTextToken)
        .then(() => {
          Cypress.log({
            name: 'login',
            message: JSON.stringify(body),
            consoleProps: () => ({ user: body }),
          });
        });
    })
    .its('body', { log: false })  times out here
```

What I'm looking for is to do something like:

```
cy.login().then(({ user }) => { 
  // use logged in user
})
```

### Question

Cypress times out on `.its(...)` line. Is this possible to do it? Looking at the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then#Yields) I couldn't find any example on what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Hi. At first sight, it is a wrong chain. Your `.its` command is chained on this callback `.then(({ body })` which does not return anything. btw, can I ask why are you setting token in the cookies and not in the sessionStorage?

Comment: @AlexIzbas feel free to answer because your answer is the correct one. Returning `{ body }` from my `then(({body}))` does the trick. I'm saving the token to cookies because we are using SSR (more specifically a Quasar app). Not sure if the server is able to use variables set in `sessionStorage`, but something to look into

Comment: Yeah, cookies are primarily for server-side reading, so makes sense. I will add my answer, even if it looks more like a remark :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(from the comments)

It happens because previously chained subject, does not return anything. An explicit return for the `body` property will fix it.